# Unable to decompose this relation to BCNF

Tags: database-design, relational-database, normalization

I have a relation

```
R = { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I }
```

And functional dependencies

```
F ={
ABC -> DE
E -> C
AB -> F
C -> G
F -> H
H -> IJ
F -> B
}
```

I am able to do simple BCNF decomposition but I can't decompose this. I have ABC as the only candidate key. Then I split it into two relations to get rid of the first FD that breaks BCNF, `E -> C`, giving me the relations

```
{ A, B, D, E, F, G, H, I, J } and { E, C }
```

But now straight away I have lost the candidate key from the first relation. So does this mean I have now have to find a new candidate key for the first relation and then continue with the process of decomposing it until we are left with no relations that violate BCNF? Could someone show me how to work out this decomposition?

**EDIT:**

OK so here is what I have gone on to do:

I currently have `{ A, B, D, E, F, G, H, I, J }` and `{ E, C }`

I find a new key for the bigger relation. This new key is `ABDEG`?

Then I continue decomposing by splitting relations wherever BCNF is violated. Here are the steps I took:

```
{ A, B, D, E, F, G, H, I, J } // { E, C }

{ A, B, D, E, G, H, I, J } // { AB, F } // { E, C }

{ A, B, D, E, G, H, J } // { H, I } // { AB, F } // { E, C }

{ A, B, D, E, G, H } // { H, J } // { H, I } // { AB, F } // { E, C }
```

So the final line is my end result. That seems to be in BCNF? Is my answer correct, am I decomposing correctly?

Comment: If ABC is a candidate key, then it follows from E->C that ABE must necessarily also be a candidate key.

Comment: Cheers, didn't spot that. I went over my results again with that in mind and I still got the same answer.

Comment: There are four candidate keys: ABC, ABE, ACF, and AEF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked your results, but if the purpose is "decompose into something that is BCNF", then your result might indeed be correct.

That does not mean that your decomposition is also the most **appropriate** to choose.

That a design is in BCNF does not mean, all by itself, that is also the best possible.

Your best chances of arriving at the most **appropriate** decomposition, is by starting with the FDs that have the least "intertwining".  E.g. H->IJ is a good candidate because neither I nor J are mentioned anywhere else.

So you get {ABCDEFGH} and {HIJ} with their respective FDs "inherited" from the original set.

Now another good candidate is C->G.  So you get {ABCDEFH} {CG} and {HIJ}.

Now another good one is F->H.  So you get  {ABCDEF} {FH} {CG} and {HIJ}.

And no you're left with the pesky set of FDs ABC->DE   E->C   AB->F   F->B.  Now you **have** to pick one of these, and accept the consequence that some other FD will have become inexpressible.

But none of this means that your solution is **wrong** (as far as getting a BCNF result is concerned).